# About the license for commercial use

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I would like to use Google Cloud Vision service in commercial purpose.

But I could not find any clear description about whether it is permitted to use that service for the commercial use without following any license condition.

Briefly my question is 2 points below.

1. Is there any license which should be followed in order to commercial use?
2. the condition for commercial use

If there is someone who have answer about them,
it would be highly appreciated that you could give me answers.

Answer (score 0):

The [Vision API FAQs documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage) mentions that is not permitted to resell the Cloud Vision API service; however, it is still possible to integrate it into applications of independent value.

Based on this, I recommend you to contact to the [GCP Sales team](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) in order to get a proper guidance about the conditions for commercial use, as well as the service license requirements that may vary based on your applications and solutions offered.

Comment: Can someone explain what "applications of independent value" means? I want to use another Google service, translate api, in a paid Android app to translate news articles. Is that allowed?